# Socket programming in yii2 to provide web service support to the mobile app

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a requirement to provide the real time data to the mobile app through web services. I have developed the project in yii2 and want to implement socket programming so that i could connect the mobile app and can send the updated real time data to the app.

For Details :
We have to provide the live tracking feature to our mobile app user.
For that we are storing the mobile app user's current location(Lat/long) and storing it on server. When any user want to track his friend(Which is the user of our app) location he can, for which we have to keep sending his friend's current location to the app so that he can see him moving on map when he is roaming anywhere.

I have google for the socket programming with Yii2 but every where i am getting the example for chat functionality through sockets.

Can any body help who has worked something matching with my requirements.

Socket programming to send data from server to mobile app client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you try ratchet socket http://socketo.me/

Comment: @SudharshanNair thanks for your reply.
ratchet is also for chatting system which engaging some javascript events. Does not supporting direct requirement of mine.

Comment: No you can do it with server side, You can create connection with server side and You mobile app users will connect using IP(hostname) and port

Comment: how many concurrent connection can be supported in this?

Comment: no limitations as per me

Comment: @SudharshanNair... Do you have any tutorial link which explain the connection of the server and mobile app using socket or any running code...?    Thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: socketo.me has examples, you have to follow that

Comment: One thing, its better to use NO SQL or mongo for DB, as there may be connection timeout issues for MySQL

Comment: Redis socket with node js is the good solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, After putting so much efforts and spent a week of time on R&D i just got what i was require.

Here i am posting the solution which i have developed for my requirements considering for those who have the similar requirements, may be it could help full for them :

Server.js

```
var app     = require('express')();
var server  = require('http').Server(app);
var io      = require('socket.io')(server);
var clientsids = {};
var response_array = get_response_array();
server.listen(8786);
io.on('connection', async function (socket) {
var uchannel = socket.handshake['query']['r_var'];
var myid     = socket.handshake['query']['myid'];
clientsids[uchannel+'_'+myid] =  socket.id;
socket.join(uchannel);
socket.emit('connectSuccess',response_array);
//sending current data to the user
socket.on('currentlocation', function(data) {
console.log("User with id :"+data.myid+ " has shared the location :    lat   :"+data.lat+",lng :"+data.lng+" in channel :"+data.channel);
//dump user location to a file for future save to the db
fileobj.savelocation(data.myid,data.lat,data.lng);
response_array = get_response_array();
response_array['msg_code'] = 103;
response_array['msg'] = get_msg_code(103);

         var datainfo = {};
             datainfo['lat'] = data.lat;
             datainfo['lng'] = data.lng;
             datainfo['channel_name'] = data.channel;
             datainfo['u_id'] = data.myid;
         response_array['data'] = datainfo;
         fileobj.dumpdata("User with id :"+data.myid+" has shared the location : lat :"+data.lat+",lng :"+data.lng+" in channel :"+data.channel+" \n"+JSON.stringify(response_array));
         io.to(data.channel).emit(data.channel, response_array); //broadcast the data to all the users in the channel
        //console.log('current clients :'+ JSON.parse(clientsids));
    }); 
 socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    //redisClient.quit();        
    socket.disconnect('disconnect');
});
```

});

Client.php

```
var room ='';
var myid ='';
var socket ='';
$( document ).ready(function() {
room = $("#channel").val();
room2 = $("#channel2").val();
myid = $("#myid").val();
socket = io.connect('serverip:port',{
    query: 'r_var='+room+'&myid='+myid
});
socket.on(room, function (data) {
$( "#notifications" ).prepend( "<p><strong>Message :" + data.msg + "    </strong>&nbsp;<strong>Channel :" + data.data.channel_name + "</strong>&nbsp;<strong>Lat :" + data.data.lat + "</strong>&nbsp;<strong>Long :" + data.data.lng + "</strong></p>" );
});
socket.on('connectSuccess', function (data) {
   $( "#notifications" ).prepend( "<p><strong>" +data.msg+ "</strong>: ");
});
});
```